# How can I place my custom file templates to the top?

Tags: xcode, xcode9, file-templates

Using Xcode 9.

I have created several custom file templates.

When creating new files, the dialog box shows my custom templates at the bottom.

How can I get them to show at to top?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/
```

...rename the folder named Custom to Source. That will move your custom file templates to the Source section, which is on the top.

[image: "Source" category in the new file dialog]

Comment: Didn't work for me on Xcode 11. I had to copy files in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Source/

Comment: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Source also works (with Xcode 15 at least)